# Error calling method on NPObject! in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, plugins, firebreath, portaudio

I've got some Visual C++ code (FireBreath) that wants to open a stream using PortAudio. After having done all the initial operations, I have this code:

```
err = Pa_OpenStream( &stream, &parametriIngresso, &parametriUscita, SAMPLE_RATE, FRAMES_PER_BUFFER, 0, My_Callback, &myData);
err = Pa_StartStream(stream);

while( ( err = Pa_IsStreamActive( stream ) ) == 1 )
    {
        Pa_Sleep(1000);
    }

err = Pa_CloseStream(stream);
```

This function is called from JavaScript, and after a certain number of seconds the plugin crashes giving me a `Error calling method on NPObject!` error on the line where it's called from in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem of thread. 
Thread principal is busy for more time from plugin and since Javascript is single-threading, it crash.
The solution is create the new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Error calling method on NPObject! is the error you get on most current browsers whenever *anything* goes wrong.  You used to be able to send exception text from a NPAPI plugin (like a firebreath plugin) but all of the browsers have stopped passing this correctly recently.

Anyway, the upshot of this is that all that error message tells you for sure is that something went wrong in your plugin; if the plugin is actually crashing, the error message "Error calling method on NPObject!" has nothing to do with the actual crash, but rather just means "we were trying to call something on a plugin that crashed". Attach a debugger and find out what caused the crash and you will be closer to finding out what is actually happening.

Comment: how I can attach a debugger in Visual Studio 2010?